# Publishing a node.js service as a workerrole to azure

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure, socket.io, azure-worker-roles

After following the guide [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/) to download and install the Windows Azure Publishing Settings I followed the guide [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/app-using-socketio/) to publish my socket.io node.js application to Azure.

When I use the publish command:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject –ServiceName NodeHelloWorld –Location "East US" -Launch
```

I get the following error:

> Publish-AzureServiceProject : You MUST specify a certificate. Call
>   Set-AzureSubscription and Select-AzureSubscription first. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Publish-AzureServiceProject
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureServiceProject], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.CloudService.PublishAzureServiceProjectCommand

Searching online I couldn't find a solution or other people with a similar problem. Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what impact this would have, but the end quote mark after "East US" is actually a "curly quote", not a "straight quote". I'd try changing that to a straight quote first (since PowerShell probably  doesn't like the curly quote); if that doesn't fix the problem, please update your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was not the issue - fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the solution was in front of me all along..
I didn't need to use Set-AzureSubscription but I did need to use Select-AzureSubscription.
What really surprised me is that the name of the subscription was very long and automatically set when I got my account.

In short:
After the process above run the following command:
Select-AzureSubscription